# unable to authorise cluster control: AMQ219016: Connection failure detected

Tags: activemq-artemis

I am trying to configure the cluster in ActiveMQ Artemis using static connectors. The whole setup is running on AKS Cluster.

Static Cluster Config for POD 0:

```xml
<acceptor name="artemis">tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpDuplicateDetection=true;supportAdvisory=false;suppressInternalManagementObjects=false;sslEnabled=true;keyStorePath=/var/lib/artemis/security/vault/my_keystore.jks;keyStorePassword=securepass</acceptor>

   <connectors>
       <connector name="netty-connector">tcp://10.1.4.211:61616</connector>
       <connector name="cluster-peer">tcp://pod1_ip:61616</connector>
   </connectors>

      <cluster-connections>
         <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
            <connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
            <retry-interval>2000</retry-interval>
            <use-duplicate-detection>true</use-duplicate-detection>
            <message-load-balancing>ON_DEMAND</message-load-balancing>
            <max-hops>1</max-hops>
            <static-connectors>
               <connector-ref>cluster-peer</connector-ref>
            </static-connectors>
         </cluster-connection>
      </cluster-connections>
```

Static Cluster Config for POD 1:

```xml
<acceptor name="artemis">tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpDuplicateDetection=true;supportAdvisory=false;suppressInternalManagementObjects=false;sslEnabled=true;keyStorePath=/var/lib/artemis/security/vault/my_keystore.jks;keyStorePassword=securepass</acceptor>

   <connectors>
       <connector name="netty-connector">tcp://10.1.4.212:61616</connector>
       <connector name="cluster-peer">tcp://pod0_ip:61616</connector>
   </connectors>

      <cluster-connections>
         <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
            <connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
            <retry-interval>2000</retry-interval>
            <use-duplicate-detection>true</use-duplicate-detection>
            <message-load-balancing>ON_DEMAND</message-load-balancing>
            <max-hops>1</max-hops>
            <static-connectors>
               <connector-ref>cluster-peer</connector-ref>
            </static-connectors>
         </cluster-connection>
      </cluster-connections>
```

The above IP `10.1.4.211` and `10.1.4.212`is respective pod's IP.

As I enable SSL in acceptor, clusters are not formed and I am getting this error -

```
WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222186: unable to authorise cluster control: AMQ219016: Connection failure detected. Unblocking a blocking call that will never get a response
```

If I remove the SSL configs, the cluster is formed, and working as expected.

The same thing is happening when I am creating clusters in docker using discovery groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the `netty-connector` and `cluster-peer` connectors you've specified for clustering are not using SSL even though the acceptor they are connecting to (i.e. listening on port `61616`) only allows SSL connections. You need to configure the connectors with the same kind of parameters you'd use for a client's connection URL, e.g.:

```xml
   <connectors>
       <connector name="netty-connector">tcp://10.1.4.211:61616?sslEnabled=true;trustStorePath=myTrustStore</connector>
       <connector name="cluster-peer">tcp://pod1_ip:61616?sslEnabled=true;trustStorePath=myTrustStore</connector>
   </connectors>
```